# Camera not displaying anything when clamped used to set restrictions in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Good day

I am trying to restrict my camera movement using a function that I am using to restrict other elements in a 2D game. When I call this function using my camera, it does something strange.

For some reason it does not display anything as soon as I called the function. I have tested the camera's position using Debug.log, and it seems to be in exactly the same place. The constraints also seem to work, but that is useless if nothing displays.

I am using a Mathf.Clamp function to try and constrain the map. I know that there are many tutorials showing how to constrain map movement, and honestly my approach seems similar.

I want to know why this function is failing. I am trying to keep things generic, and am already using this function to restrict the movement of other game elements.

My code looks like this:

```
    int cameraSpeed = 10;  
    GameObject camera;
    int maxX = 20;
    int minX = -20;
    int maxY = 20;
    int minY = -20;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void constrain(GameObject obj)
    {
        Vector2 pos = obj.transform.position;
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -maxX, maxX);
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, -maxY, maxY);
        obj.transform.position = pos;
    }

    void Start () {
        camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            camera.transform.Translate(new Vector2(cameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            camera.transform.Translate(new Vector2(-cameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            camera.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, -cameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            camera.transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, cameraSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
        Debug.Log(camera.transform.position.x);
        Debug.Log(camera.transform.position.y);
        constrain(camera);
    }
```

Screenshot of game without constraints:
[image]

Screenshot of game with constraints:
[image]

I am new to Unity and am trying to understand it thoroughly. Any advice would be greatly appropriated.

Comment: Can you update the screenshots with the camera object selected so it's information is in the Inspector? I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @Foggzie thank you for the reply. I have updated as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Z-position of your camera is being set to 0. All of your other objects have the same Z-position, so the camera won't render them.

Change constrain() to:

```
public float zPos = -10
public void constrain(GameObject obj)
{
    Vector3 pos = obj.transform.position;
    pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -maxX, maxX);
    pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, -maxY, maxY);
    pos.z = zPos
    obj.transform.position = pos;
}
```

and that should fix it.

EDIT: The reason that this is happening is because you were using a Vector2 for your camera position. In Unity, a Vector2 is a Vector3 with a z-value of 0.

Comment: Thank you @DerwB! That definitely is what is happening. Your solution is however not 100% perfect. It moves everything, including my camera, to a different z index. This means that my other game components that I am not constraining are now disappearing. I have managed to fix this by making sure that I position everything else in 3D space, managing the z index of each. I was however wondering if there might be a simpler solution that does not require this increased overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the bug with @DerwB's assistance. I now see that the camera needs to be on a lower z index than the objects it is displaying. DerwB's answer is close to a solution, but it does not allow the function to be reused to constrain other objects.

I have thus modified the function as below:

```
public void constrain(GameObject obj, bool isCamera = false)
    {
        Vector3 pos = obj.transform.position;
        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp(pos.x, -maxX, maxX);
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp(pos.y, -maxY, maxY);
        if(isCamera)
            pos.z = 0;
        else
            pos.z = 1;
        obj.transform.position = pos;
    }
```

You then call the function as follows for the camera:

```
  GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
  constrain(camera.gameObject,true); //if you are constraining the camera object
```

And like this if you are referencing other game objects:

```
  GameObject player= GameObject.Find("Player");
  constrain(player.gameObject,true); //skip the optional parameter if not referencing the camera
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to have the `if` or `else` statement at all, as long as you've changed `pos` to a `Vector3`, it'll retain the z information properly and then you just have to have the right z values set on the object in the first place.
The original problem was that `pos` being a `Vector2` was stripping that value away.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Foggzie. That makes sense, but it does to seem to work like that? If I have the objects remain on their original Z, I would expect to see exactly what I saw without calling the function. My characters disappears off of my screen however unless I ensure that I place the camera on a lower Z position. Its pretty confusing to be honest?